# JavaScript - Popups not working

Tags: javascript, popup, alert, confirm

I tried using alert() and confirm() in JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
My Website
</title>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<h2 align=center>My Website</h2>
<p align=center> <button onclick=“myFunction()”>click to enter</button> </p>        
<script type=text/javascript>
function myFunction() {
    alert(“u sure?”);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Before you point it out, no, quotation marks glitch everything out on my website.
I tried something similar to this on another computer and it worked.
Is it just my computer?

Comment: Those double quotes look off `“` should be `"`

Comment: I recommend using a different editor. What editor are you currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely with your double quotes.  `“` should be `"`:

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert("u sure?");
}
```

```html
<p align=center> <button onclick="myFunction()">click to enter</button> </p>
```

Comment: Just another reason why MS Word isn't a very good text editor!

Comment: Lol.  That will do it! If this answer solved your problem, please be sure to mark it so. Happy coding!

Comment: Oh you are on a Mac? Then I would recommend any of the following:
sublime text, brackets, text wrangler, bbedit, etc. I personally switch between sublime text and brackets based upon what I am working on.

Comment: @KJPrice I worked it out. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Glad to hear it. What was your solution, out of curiosity?

Comment: @KJPrice sorry about taking a while to reply. I found out on all Macs there are "smart quotes". I disabled these in system preferences ▸ keyboard